# persistent: How do I get the I in ACID

Tags: haskell, persistent, yesod

Assume I'm doing the following steps in a transaction:

- read some data A from the database
- do some calculation based on it
- write some data B to the database

Is it possible to make this transaction fail if A has changed in the mean time?

In short: How do I achieve isolation in the persistent package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used `persistent` myself, but the [Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) mentions that

> One important thing to note is that everything which occurs inside a
>   single call to `runSqlConn` runs in a single transaction. This has two
>   important implications:
>
> - For many databases, committing a transaction
>     can be a costly activity. By putting multiple steps into a single
>     transaction, you can speed up code dramatically.
> - If an exception is
>     thrown anywhere inside a single call to `runSqlConn`, all actions will
>     be rolled back (assuming your backend has rollback support).

Whether this gives you isolation guarantees probably depends on whether the given back-end gives isolation guarantees for transactions.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to configure the back end from persistent?